# Information on same row but different columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble with my css. I am trying to have my contact information, the quote, and my contact form to be in the same row but different columns. And also why is it that my html doesn't all fit on one page, I can scroll to the rigth and there's just empty white space. I figure its because I added -1.23em in my navbars margin; However, I only did this because my navbar was not filling the whole page. Here is a link to my gist and bitballon. Thank you in advance.

https://gist.github.com/bklynbest/a19565b1b5289f045919e76d657848ea

http://sad-goodall-e4f115.bitballoon.com

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. NOT a gist or your website. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a `.row` div in the nested directly under the `body` on line 103 that is causing the page to spread past 100% width

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and
>   house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in
>   your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container
>   is nestable. [bootstrap containers](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container)

Regarding the contact info your nesting and class names are not correct, you currently have the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <div id="quote">...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="contact">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
```

you will need to change this to follow [bootstrap3 grid](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) conventions, something like the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="contact">
       <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div id="quote">...</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="contact">...</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
          <form>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```